# Disabling AD Connect using AzureAD v2 for Powershell

Tags: powershell, azure, active-directory

I have uninstalled AD Connect from our on-premises server and now I would like to disable AD Connect sync feature on my Azure Directory. However, there is no option to do it from the portal.

In the past, this could be done with `Set-MsolDirSyncEnabled` but this command is no longer present in AzureAD v2 for Powershell. How can I disable AD Connect on my Azure directory now?

[image: AD Connect Enabled]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I have not find the command to disable directory sync in ADv2 PowerShell.

As a workaround, we can via classic portal to disable the directory sync, like this:

[image]